# Angularjs bootstrap tab

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Below is my code for bootstrap tabs. When I click the checkbox , I want to remove 1,2 tabs and add 1 new tab.
That is I have already handled. But the tab-content active not working properly. It will show other tab content also.

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="enableDirectBalance" ng-model="enableDirectBalance" />
           <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li ng-if="!enableDirectBalance" ng-class="{active:!enableDirectBalance}"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#A">Auth</a></li>
                <li ng-if="enableDirectBalance" ng-class="{active:enableDirectBalance}"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#B">DirectBalance</a></li>
                <li ng-if="!enableDirectBalance"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#C">Balance</a></li>
                <li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#D">Redeem</a></li>
                <li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#E">Void</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="A" class="tab-pane  "  ng-class="{active:!enableDirectBalance}">

                </div>
                <div id="B" class="tab-pane  "  ng-class="{active:enableDirectBalance}">

                </div>
                <div id="C" ng-if="!enableDirectBalance" class="tab-pane  ">

                </div>
                <div id="D"  class="tab-pane  ">

                </div>
                <div id="E" class="tab-pane  ">

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: ng-if="!enableDirectBalance" in tabb content's <div id="A" class="tab-pane  "  ng-class="{active:!enableDirectBalance}">

Comment: Suppose im on tabE and im clicking checkbox at that time 2 tab will be active

Comment: you should use a counter that limits at the amount of tabs you want and give each tab a number(e.g. 1-5), have an incrementer and on each tab you could go `ng-if="counter === tabnum"` that will solve your problem with being on e and wanting to go back to a

Answer (score 0):

IMO, a more elegant way would be to handle the logic of which tabs to show inside your angularJs controller and keep your html simple.

To summarise, keep an array of which tabs to show. Watch the checkbox variable, when its value switches, adjust the tabs array as per your logic.

So the html and controller would look something like this -
(Note that I have used isActive attributes inside the tabs array, which is used to decide which will the active tab when the checkbox value switches)

Complete Code - https://codepen.io/sarthakj178/pen/MZwZqw

### HTML code snippet

---

```
<input type="checkbox" id="enableDirectBalance" ng-model="enableDirectBalance" />
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{active: tab.isActive}">
      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#{{tab.href}}">
        {{tab.title}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" id="{{tab.href}}" class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: tab.isActive}">{{tab.content}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

### Controller code snippet

---

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
  $scope.tabs = [];
  $scope.$watch("enableDirectBalance", function(enableDirectBalance) {
    if (enableDirectBalance) {
      $scope.tabs = [
        {
          href: "B",
          title: "DirectBalance",
          isActive: true,
          content: "Direct Balance Content"
        },
        {
          href: "D",
          title: "Redeem",
          content: "Redeem Content"
        },
        {
          href: "E",
          title: "Void",
          content: "Void Content"
        }
      ];
    } else {
      $scope.tabs = [
        {
          href: "A",
          title: "Auth",
          isActive: true,
          content: "Auth Content"
        },
        {
          href: "C",
          title: "Balance",
          content: "Balance Content"
        },
        {
          href: "D",
          title: "Redeem",
          content: "Redeem Content"
        },
        {
          href: "E",
          title: "Void",
          content: "Void Content"
        }
      ];
    }
  });
});
```